# Clojurescript compiler options in leiningen

Tags: clojurescript, leiningen, figwheel

An error message in my browser has informed me that:

```
ClojureScript could not load :main, did you forget to specify :asset-path?
```

According to [the documentation](https://clojurescript.org/reference/compiler-options), :asset-path is a compiler option. What is the correct place in my leiningen configuration file for a compiler option such as :asset-path? It doesn't seem to work at the top level.

The project is freshly generated using this command:

```
lein new figwheel-main <name> -- --reagent
```

I'm hosting the website on my own server, with the output files hosted at `/static/cljs-out`, hence the need for the :asset-path option.

Leiningen version is 2.9.1, figwheel-main version is 0.2.16

Comment: Without sharing the project, it's hard to guess correctly.  This is the config for figwheel-main: https://figwheel.org/docs/compile_config.html and this for clsj-build with leiningen (examples with compiler options):  https://github.com/emezeske/lein-cljsbuild#multiple-build-configurations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The :asset-path option can be placed in the build specific configuration file, `dev.cljs.edn` in my case. This file is found in the project's root folder.

```
^{:watch-dirs ["test" "src"]
  :css-dirs ["resources/public/css"]
  :auto-testing true
   }
{:main flaglib2.core
 :asset-path "/static/cljs-out/dev"}
```

This answer is possibly specific to figwheel-main projects. The rules seem to be different for [cljs-build](https://github.com/emezeske/lein-cljsbuild#multiple-build-configurations) projects, as per cfrick's comment above.